# Why two return registers (in many procedure calling conventions/ABIs)

Tags: c, assembly, arm

While looking at calling conventions I noticed (specifically with ARM, but also with x86 System V) that many/most specify two return registers.
As C and derived languages can only ever return one value directly, and some hypothetical language that can return more could return an arbitrary amount of values: Why are there specifically two in these specifications?
(i.e. is there a specific language that uses exactly two return values?)

Comment: Without specific citation I can only speculate that it is for returning 64-bit values with 32-bit registers.

Comment: Two return registers does not necessarily mean two return values. It could be a single value that only fits in two registers. E.g. a 64 bit integer on a 32 bit system.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/bBsZ3t) is an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a citation from [Procedure Call Standard for the Arm
Architecture
Release 2019Q1.1](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0042/g/aapcs32.pdf?_ga=2.45343725.874957675.1576000939-842767637.1536951533), page 19

> Handling values larger than 32 bits Fundamental types larger than 32
>   bits may be passed as parameters to, or returned as the result of,
>   function calls. When these types are in core registers the following
>   rules apply:
>   • A double-word sized type is passed in two consecutive
>   registers (e.g., r0 and r1, or r2 and r3). The content of the
>   registers is as if the value had been loaded from memory
>   representation with a single LDM instruction.
>   • A 128-bit
>   containerized vector is passed in four consecutive registers. The
>   content of the registers is as if the value had been loaded from
>   memory with a single LDM instruction.

So 4 return registers `r0`-`r3` defined in the ABI are used to return a *single* value for C types that do not fit into a single register.

Comment: +1, `e.g., r0 and r1, or r2 and r3` - I would assume that this **or** only applies to parameters' passing. The 64 bit  return value uses r0, r1 only, no choice.

Comment: @tum_ The second bullet is speaking of using 4 registers all together

Comment: Yes. My comment was about the first bullet. It is OK too - I got puzzled with that 'or' for a minute because the question is about the return value.